# Setting DevOps Default Project Collection

Tags: devops

I would like to know if there is a way to set a certain Project Collection to be the default Project Collection in DevOps when a user uses the main DevOps URL?

Comment: Hi, welcome! For you get helped you must provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).